# Getting SSL certificate for a sub-domain

Tags: security-certificate, subdomain

Our company owns a domain say **www.mycompany.com**. I understand that it is trivial to get an SSL certificate for above domain since we do have a website running on that address. We want a certificate for a subdomain say **sub.mycompany.com**. We intend to use this sub-domain in our organisation network only and have no plans to publish a public website on this subdomain.

So the question is "Is it necessary to have a DNS entry for subdomain, resolving to our IP address and host some page on that address?" I hope proving that main domain is in our control, we can get an SSL certificate for sub domain also. Is it possible?

Comment: Why not get a wildcard SSL cert for **mycompany.com** so that you can set up SSL on it and any of its subdomains?

Comment: It **is** certainly an option but a wildcard certificate would be more expensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A certificate authority should not care whether or not you have a publicly viewable HTTPS site for the common name you're requesting.